# Is it safe to emit 10 times per second with socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, socket.io, limit

on my site I have a feature that needs a fast respond on what's happening during 5 seconds,

Every 2 minutes I am sending 50 times a message (number between 0 and 360) in 5 seconds to every user. (10 emits /s), 
and also receiving a maximum of 100 message /s during these 5 secondes).

I would like to know if it's safe to send and receive that much?, if I won't be blocked by some firewall or use too much resources. If it will still work when 5000 people will be on my site at once? And if it's the good way to do it?

Thanks, best regards

Comment: TCP does not transfer packets - it's an octet stream.

Comment: If you mean 'application protocol units transferred by a protocol on top of TCP', then it kinda depends on your message size.  If it's a 10GB message, you may have problems.

Comment: So, how shall I correct my post, to say what is does when we write io.sockets.emit(....

Comment: @MartinJames The content of each message is just a number between 0 and 360

Answer (score -3):

It is safe, until someone will proof another.